# Invalid postback or callback argument error

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback, postback, repeater

I am using a repeater and I am getting this error after clicking the button (with a Command)

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

I did some research, and I read that I need to set EnableViewState=”false”, didn't work.\

Also tried that in the web.config file, didn't work.

Used also updatepanel: same problem.

What is this kind of error? In my previous ASP project this worked fine for me without changing settings.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, my guess is that you are binding the data for your control before the events are fired (i.e. data binding in the `Page_Load`, because that is called before the event handler code).

You need to only bind the data in `Page_Load` when the page is not a postback (i.e. first load of the page and not from event clicks), like this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // Bind repeater data here
}
```

Then at the end of your event handler (i.e. your command click), then you should re-bind the data as the last line of that method or part of the method where you have the logic pertinent to the user clicking.

Comment: Wow really didn't know that. This worked awesome! Could you maybe explain me more? Why do I need a postback? Why isn't it just working without it (sorry I don't understand postbacks, read alot about it...)

Comment: Well it is not really that you need a postback, but rather the fact that a postback is happening that is of consequence here. ASP.NET WebForms is based on the premise that you request a server-side page that has server-side controls, each of which in turn have events that cause postbacks (i.e. the whole page is created again, along with all the controls on it). This is where the timing of events comes into play or what is referred to as the page lifecycle. `Page_Load` is one of the events in this lifecycle and it happens before click events of any of the controls within the page.

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms is a mature technology and many great applications have been and continue to be built with it today. The issue comes when you want to work more closely with the HTML/CSS/JavaScript of your application. With the ease of server controls you lose a fair amount of control over how that control renders its HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Also, client-side logic (i.e. jQuery) becomes problematic when interacting with the ASP.NET WebForms page lifecycle, because WebForms never really intended to have the client do any major lifting with JavaScript, thus you see the rise of ASP.NET MVC, etc.